# KivyMD menu with multiple screens

Tags: menu, kivy, kivymd

I want to use a KivyMD Menu with multiple Screens. In the documentation of KivyMD it is only shown how you can create it with the App Class. However, my goal is to use the Menu in an application with multiple screens, thats why I posted an example code with two screens. When I run this code, I get the error message:

caller=self.ids.drop_item,

File "kivy\properties.pyx", line 863, in kivy.properties.ObservableDict.**getattr**

AttributeError: 'super' object has no attribute '**getattr**'

Does anyone know how to fix it? Thank you.

**main.py**

```
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen, ScreenManager
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivymd.uix.menu import MDDropdownMenu
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty


Window.size = (400, 800)


class FirstScreen(Screen):

    drop_item = ObjectProperty(None)

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        menu_items = [{"icon": "git", "text": f"Item {i}"} for i in range(5)]
        self.menu = MDDropdownMenu(
            caller=self.ids.drop_item,
            items=menu_items,
            callback=self.set_item,
            width_mult=4,
        )

    def set_item(self, instance_menu_item):
        self.ids.drop_item.text = instance_menu_item.text
        self.menu.dismiss()



class SecondScreen(Screen):
    pass

class WindowManager(ScreenManager):
    pass

GUI = Builder.load_file("main.kv")

class App(MDApp):

    def build(self):
        return GUI


if __name__ == "__main__":
    App().run()
```

**main.kv**

```
WindowManager:
    FirstScreen:
        name: 'firstscreen'
    SecondScreen:
        name: 'secondscreen'

<FirstScreen>:
    drop_item: drop_item
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'

        MDDropDownItem:
            id: drop_item
            pos_hint: {'center_x': .5, 'center_y': .5}
            text: "Select"
            on_release: root.menu.open()

        Button:
            text: "Go to SecondScreen"
            on_press:
                app.root.current = "secondscreen"

<SecondScreen>:

    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'

        Button:
            text: "Go to FirstScreen"
            on_press:
                app.root.current = "firstscreen"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your reference to `self.ids.drop_item` is happening before the `ids` are available. You can fix that by using `Clock.schedule_once()` to delay that access slightly. Here is a modified version of your `FirstScreen` that does that:

```
class FirstScreen(Screen):

    drop_item = ObjectProperty(None)

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        Clock.schedule_once(self._post_init)

    def _post_init(self, dt):
        menu_items = [{"icon": "git", "text": f"Item {i}"} for i in range(5)]
        self.menu = MDDropdownMenu(
            caller=self.ids.drop_item,
            items=menu_items,
            callback=self.set_item,
            width_mult=4,
        )

    def set_item(self, instance_menu_item):
        self.ids.drop_item.text = instance_menu_item.text
        self.menu.dismiss()
```

I suspect that you will need to move your loading of the `kv` file to inside the `App`:

```
# GUI = Builder.load_file("main.kv")

class App(MDApp):

    def build(self):
        GUI = Builder.load_file("main.kv")
        return GUI
```